# Is it OK to add a link to an issue on GitHub

Tags: discussion, comments

I am affiliated with dot42 (a C# compiler for Android; free for non-commercial use - if relevant). When a user asks a quesion that leads to an issue, is it ok to add a comment pointing to that issue on GitHub? It feels somewhat abusive but at the same time unnatural to not let the OP know that we logged an issue and where.

Example:
[dot42 jar import is missing methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21638631/dot42-jar-import-is-missing-methods)

Comment: I'd certainly add such a comment. It is more than okay for you to do so. You could perhaps give it a little more context; *this is actually a bug in the compiler, see ....*.

Comment: I don't see any harm with a little comment saying "This is a known issue, logged *here*". Useful for everyone who's interested.

Comment: If the question is about something that is a bug, and the only fix is a bugfix, then that would be acceptable as an answer as well.  But try to pad it out a little.  Maybe with a workaround, or a more detailed description of what the bug is?  Anyhow, with the question answered it can be closed out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That'd be more than fine; others that come to Stack Overflow with the same problem will see the comment and can at least then know that this is a known issue and that the project is aware of it.

I'd give the comment a little more context; all you did was post a link. Something along the lines of:

> This is an issue with dot42 itself; I've opened a ticket at https://github.com/dot42/dot42/issues/7

That's not spamming, that's being helpful.